# Angular view encapsulation with external libraries

Tags: angular, angular2viewencapsulation

I use an external component in my component. I want to do some styling on this external component. Because of Angular View Encapsulation all css I define in my component are not propagated to this external component which is used in my html-template. In order to enable this propagation I set

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

That works. But then my css is applied to my whole project not to a particular component only. What I need is to tell Angular somehow: "Apply this css to this component and all child components of it, also external ones". Is that possible at all?

Comment: Not entirely sure on your use case but have you had a look at using :host or ::ng-deep - https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this in your css. However, be carefull as ::ng-deep is quite a powerfull combinator and can cause problems if not used correctly.
Also from the Angular website:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular.

CSS:

```
 :host { color: red; }
 
 :host ::ng-deep parent {
   color:blue;
 }
 :host ::ng-deep child{
   color:orange;
 }
 :host ::ng-deep child.class1 {
   color:yellow;
 }
 :host ::ng-deep child.class2{
   color:pink;
 }
```

HTML:

```
  Angular2                                //red
  <parent>                                //blue
      <child></child>                     //orange
      <child class="class1"></child>      //yellow
      <child class="class2"></child>      //pink
  </parent>
```

Comment: That would work but it is deprecated as you told. Is there any up to date solution? I mean otherwise since the support is being removed from major browsers it wouldn't work anymore later.

Comment: @EwgenijSokolovski There is not any up to date solutions for this. For now ng-deep will keep working until they find a lasting solution for shadow piercing css.